# How to use components from modules in others lazy load modules

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to use some components from a specific module inside of others components from lazy load modules.

I gonna show you example for better understanding!

```
project:
app.module
app.route
shared.module

modules/
    lazy-load-1.module
    lazy-load-2.module
    reusable.module
```

inside of each module I have imported a shared.module.
inside of reusable.module, I have some components to be used inside of others module, but that others module are lazy load modules.

ex:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ someImportsHere ],
  declarations: [ someImportsHere ],
  exports:      [ someImportsHere ]
})
export class SharedModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ SharedModule, ReusableModule ],
  declarations: [ someImportsHere ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'lazy-load-1',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/lazy-load-1/lazy-load-1.module#LazyLoad1Module',
  },
  {
    path: 'lazy-load-2',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/lazy-load-2/lazy-load-2.module#LazyLoad2Module',
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'lazy-load-1'
  }
];


@NgModule({
   exports: [
      RouterModule
   ],
   imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
   ]
})

export class AppRouter { }
```

modules/

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ SharedModule ],
  declarations: [ TestComponent ],
})
export class LazyLoad1Module { }

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ SharedModule ],
  declarations: [ OtherTestComponent ],
})
export class LazyLoad2Module { }

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ SharedModule ],
  declarations: [ ReusableComponent ],
  exports: [ ReusableComponent ]
})
export class ReusableModule { }
```

I am trying something like this above, but when I try to use a ReusableComponent inside of LazyLoad modules I got this error:
rejection: Error: Template parse errors:
'app-reusable-component' is not a known element.

Comment: The lazy module needs to import the reusable one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have multiple modules and want to share your component to other modules you need to `export` it

like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [your_component],
  exports: [your_component]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of lazy loaded modules can not be used in other modules. you have to move that component in shared module and then import that module in that module in which you want to use that component.

Comment: exactly, this is the doubt!
I need the shared module inside of Reusable module.
if I import Shared module in Reusable module and import Reusable module  inside of shared module to be used to others module. I got circular dependency in it.

Comment: Why do you want to import Reusable module inside Shared module ? It's look like both modules have the same purpose, so you should just make "one module" or  add a third small module with the code needed by both module

Comment: No no, you just have to declare all your reusable components in shared module and just simply import shared module in those module in which you want to use these components,

Answer (score 2):

- Step1: Make sure Reusable ** components **  are exported form ReusableModule.
- Step2: If u don't wont to import ReusableModule in LazyLoaded Module than in  **SharedModule** you have to  **RE-EXPORT** the ReusableModule in order to accessible by other module.

  - As Modules have private scope.
  - All components inside a module are only accessible with in the same module in order to access by other module you have to add in **exports []** of a module.

```
  @NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [Component1, Component2],
    exports: [Component1, Component2]
  })
  export class ReusableModule {
  }

  @NgModule({
    imports: [ReusableModule],
    declarations: [someImportsHere],
    exports: [ReusableModule, 'IF ANY OTHER COMPONENST TO EXPORT FROM SHARED MODULE']
  })
  export class SharedModule {
  }

  @NgModule({
    imports: [SharedModule],
    declarations: [OtherTestComponent]
  })
  export class LazyLoad2Module {
  }
```